# Ball passing through paddle in Pong game

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making *another* Pong clone using HTML5 canvas and JavaScript. The problem I'm having can best be described in this diagram:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPIOH.png]

If the ball is moving at 10px per frame, I can't just test if the ball is touching the paddle, as it is possible that the ball has surpassed the paddle in that frame-step.

Is there any way to test if the ball has collided with the paddle?

Edit: The only 2 solutions I can think of at the moment are:

[image: Test at every position]

or

[image: Make a collision area 10px behind the paddle]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can detect collisions by determining if the line defined by the paddle and the incremental transit line intersect. If they do, then you can apply the bounce logic at the intersection point.

Hope that helps.

Bob

Take a look here:

http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.97/parsons1.html

Remember you geometry is simpler because you have a vertical line as the paddle. Here is the simplification (check my math here):

```
// line 1 (x1,y1) to (x2,y2)
var x1 = -1.0;
var y1 = 1.0;
var x2 = 1.0;
var y2 = -1.0;
// line 2 (x3,y3) to (x4,y4)
// note: this is the paddle and y3=y4
var x3 = -1.0;
var y3 = 0.5;
var x4 = 1.0;
var y4 = 0.5;

​var ix, iy;
function calculateIntersection(){
  var ixtop = x1*(y2-y3) + x2*(y3-y1);
  var ixbot = y2 - y1;
  var ix = ixtop/ixbot;

  var iy = y3;
}​
```

I believe this is the most efficient approach and will provide an accurate answer. Moving diagonally through the pixel matrix will result in artifacts if you don't have sufficient resolution.

Comment: Hrm, I'd have to do some googling to figure out how to do this in JavaScript.

Comment: You can further narrow down when you have to apply this by looking at the y1 and y2 values. If they don't cross the y value of the paddle, skip the computation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bob! I'll use the solution you've made as well as this last comment to make it even more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Complicated solution, vector stuff.

Simple solution, instead if moving the ball by simply adding 10px, move it by 1px 10 times and check each time whether it collides:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   moveBallByOne();
   if (ballCollision()) { // you could check for a simple bounding box overlap here
       invertBallDirection();
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: This is inefficient. Better to directly calculate the collision point.

Comment: Uh, that totally depends, throwing in some vector stuff with calls to some math function could be just as slow as doing a trivial amount of compares.

Comment: I might use this solution, but only when the ball is within 10px from the paddle, seeing as though the paddle's x position is constant.

Answer (score 1):

Every time your ball hops ten pixels, you have to calculate each position in between to make sure it isn't trying to pass through a solid object, as you have seen will happen.

Comment: +1 That's the essence of the solution - he needs to track any changes between the last displayed frame and the current frame.

Comment: I agree, but without seeing any of his code, this is all I can suggest.

Comment: Again, not the most efficient.

Comment: His app is a canvas with two lines and a circle, running on a modern browser. I would spring for the easier method to solve this, as opposed to the "efficient" solution.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you either have a `dx` and `dy` which is the delta of the ball coordinate per movement, or an angle (say θ = theta), so in this case dx is 10 * cos(th) and dy is 10 * sin(th).

You just need to see, whether x + dx is past the paddle's x-coordinate, say 600, and if so, for simplicity, say it takes 2/3 of dx to reach there, so you can use y + dy * (2/3) to find out the y where the ball will end up, when the ball reach the x-coordinate of the paddle.

If that y is less than the paddle's top edge (the top y), or greater than the paddle bottom edge (the bottom y), then it is a miss.  Otherwise, it is a hit.

Comment: "say it takes 2/3 of dx to reach there" - thats the hard part to work out though.